# Can't figure out a mapreduce algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, mapreduce, ecmascript-6

I have this input array already sorted on the key:

```
var sortedArray = [ [ 'de', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'elle', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'elle', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'la', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'la', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'la', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'le', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'maison', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'voiture', [ 1 ] ],
                    [ 'voiture', [ 1 ] ] 
];
```

I want to obtain this reduced Array :

```
[ [ 'de', [ 1 ] ],
  [ 'elle', [ 1, 1 ] ],
  [ 'la', [ 1, 1, 1 ] ],
  [ 'le', [ 1 ] ],
  [ 'maison', [ 1 ] ],
  [ 'voiture', [ 1, 1 ] ] 
];
```

I proceed like that :

```
sortedArray.forEach((elem, index, arr) => {
   if (elem[0] === arr[index + 1][0]){
      arr[index][1].push(1);
      arr.splice(index + 1, 1);
   }
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

But I can't understand why I obtain this result:

```
 [ [ 'de', [ 1 ] ],
   [ 'elle', [ 1, 1 ] ],
   [ 'la', [ 1, 1 ] ],
   [ 'la', [ 1 ] ],
   [ 'le', [ 1 ] ],
   [ 'maison', [ 1 ] ],
   [ 'voiture', [ 1, 1 ] ] 
 ]
```

Help would be apreciated.

Comment: Do not use `splice` on an array you're currently iterating.

Comment: Why do you mention mapreduce but only use `forEach`? With `reduce` you probably wouldn't have the problem.

Comment: yes it's just a part of my mapreduce algorithm. that works of course with a traditional for-loop in a java way. but I try o migrate my code in a fonctional way (ES6)

Comment: Yes. `forEach` and `splice` are not functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're splicing your array while iterating over it without resetting your current index. One way to get the desired result while using splice is to do something like this:

```
sortedArray.forEach((elem, index, arr) => {
   while (arr[index + 1] && elem[0] === arr[index + 1][0]){
      arr[index][1].push(1);
      arr.splice(index + 1, 1);
   }
});
```

Basically we're changing the `if` statement to a `while` loop and adding an extra check.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot,  its exactly what I need

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to create a new array. Because the original array is sorted, you only need to push `1` to the last item in the array, as long as it's the same as the current item, and add a new item whenever that's not true:

```js
var sortedArray = [
  ['de', [1]],
  ['elle', [1]],
  ['elle', [1]],
  ['la', [1]],
  ['la', [1]],
  ['la', [1]],
  ['le', [1]],
  ['maison', [1]],
  ['voiture', [1]],
  ['voiture', [1]]
];

var result = sortedArray.reduce(function(result, item) {
  if (!result.length || item[0] !== result[result.length - 1][0]) { // check if 1st results array is empty or if current item 'key' doesn't match the last item it result
    result.push([item[0], []]); // push a new 'key' item with an empty array of 1s
  }

  result[result.length - 1][1].push(1); // push 1 to last item in result
  
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting too